# How to scroll `div` with `overflow:auto` using arrows

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `div` with `overflow:auto` with plenty of buttons and arrow down select the next item and arrow up select previous item. I'm wondering how can I force this `div` to scroll when select next item, i.e. to scroll it into view. For now when I choose the item that is not visible the `div` does not scroll and I can't see the active item. Here is how it look like and my code:

[image]

**EDIT** I've used `refs` to handle scrolling, see below code.

```
interface PopupListProps<T> {
  items: T[];
  command: (data: any) => void;
  render: (data: T) => ReactNode;
  map?: (data: T) => any;
}

export const PopupList = forwardRef(
  <T extends unknown>(
    { items, command, render, map = (data) => data }: PopupListProps<T>,
    ref: Ref<unknown>
  ) => {
    let refs: RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>[] = [];
    for (let item of items) {
      let ref = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
      refs.push(ref);
    }
    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

    const selectItem = (index: number) => {
      const item = items[index];

      if (item) {
        command(map(item));
      }
    };

    const upHandler = () => {
      let index = (selectedIndex + items.length - 1) % items.length;
      setSelectedIndex(index);
      refs[index].current?.scrollIntoView({ block: 'nearest' });
    };

    const downHandler = () => {
      let index = (selectedIndex + 1) % items.length;
      setSelectedIndex(index);
      refs[index].current?.scrollIntoView({ block: 'nearest' });
    };

    const enterHandler = () => {
      selectItem(selectedIndex);
    };

    useEffect(() => setSelectedIndex(0), [items]);

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      onKeyDown: ({ event }: { event: KeyboardEvent }) => {
        if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
          upHandler();
          return true;
        }

        if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
          downHandler();
          return true;
        }

        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
          enterHandler();
          return true;
        }

        return false;
      },
    }));

    return (
      <div className='popup-list'>
        {items.length ? (
          items.map((item, index) => (
            <button
              ref={refs[index]}
              className={`popup-list-item ${index === selectedIndex ? 'is-selected' : ''}`}
              key={index}
              onClick={() => selectItem(index)}
            >
              {render(item)}
            </button>
          ))
        ) : (
          <div className='px-[6px] py-[2px]'>Brak wyników</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

Now I've got the following error:
[image]

When I click `:` the popup correctly appears, scrolling via keyboard works but when I type sth to filter results, I've got above error. Any ideas what is the reason?

Comment: Does [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) not work?

Comment: works! But now there is another problem, see my updated question